# Search filter using a computed property in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue project where I have created a Vue component to display a list of Blogs. This component imports a JS file containing an array for each blog listing.

There is a HTML input that I have linked to a computed property in order to allow a user to search. The for loop would then filter the blog listing and show relevant results. However, altough the full list shows on load, when I enter a search query in the input all content disappears and the error in the console says "Cannot read property 'match' of undefined". What am I doing wrong?

My code is as follow;

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="blog in filteredBlogs">
      {{blog.blogName}}
  </li>
</ul>


import blogs from "./../data/blogs";
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            blogs: blogs,
            search:'',
        };
    },
    computed: {
      filteredBlogs:function(){
        return this.blogs.filter((blog) => {
           return blog.blogName.match(this.search);
        });
      }
    }
};
```

Comment: Your Vue instance does not have a `blogs` key in its data object, so `this.blogs` is nothing. I'm surprised that the blogs list even shows up in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

Replace this.blogs.filter by blogs.filter. "this" is the current Vue instance and you import blogs from file system.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `this.blogs.filter( ... )`, ***this*** refers to the current Vue instance. So, Vue is going to look in the `data` object for `blogs`, which does not exist there.

Without seeing the rest of your app, I'm not sure why you are importing `blogs` and saving it to the `clubs` key in your Vue instance. But to fix your current problem, you could change your `filteredBlogs` computed prop to either:

1. `this.clubs.filter( ... )`, OR
2. `blogs.filter( ... )`

See this working JS Fiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/voveson/7awythx8/8/

Comment: Apologies, clubs was a typo .. should have been blogs. Thank you for the fiddle. I will take time to go over your answer to learn and modify my code.